# MySQL insert and join table with NOT IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I want to insert data from a table and i don't want the same date data again imported on my destination table.

For example- I have date as a column on my source and destination both table and i dont want same date data in my destination table. the date column is same on both table, and number of columns are also same in both tables.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Add a unique constraint so rows cannot be duplicated.  Without sample data and desired results, it is rather hard to be more explicit.

Comment: Does your data have no such date duplicates now? *I have date as a column on my source and destination both table and i dont want same date data in my destination table.* I.e. you want to prevent some date insertion into a table when this date is already present in any (this or another) table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
select * 
  from source_table s
 where not exists
      (select 1 from destination_table d where d.date = s.date)
```

Answer (score 2):

filter those days and insert

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
select a.* from source a
where a.date not in ( select date from destination_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the destination table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Destination (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Property1 PropertyType, 
    Property2 PropertyType,
    etc.....
    UniqueDate DATE,
    UNIQUE (UniqueDate)
);
```

Remember to substitute PropertyX and PropertyType with your own properties and types, as well as rename UniqueDate

This code will set a UNIQUE constraint on your Date Column.